# Share data between Angular reducers

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a situation in my app where I need to share data between reducers.

```
State:
{
   ...
   itemDetails,
   settings
}
```

In the `itemDetails` store, I need to update some data and to be able to do this I need some data from the `settings` store.

(I’m also using facades.)

Is there a possibility to share data between reducers like `redux-thunk` in react or something like this?

I also have other two options to do this:

1. Send that settings data to the facade method as a function parameter.
2. Inject `settingsFacades` in `itemDetailsFacades` and send those data directly in the action.

But I’m curious if is there a more elegant method to share data between reducers.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can just access your store to get the data. For example in an effect it would look like this

```
constructor(private store$: Store<AppState>) {}

@Effect() specialEffect$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SOME_ACTION)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .map(([action: Action, storeState: AppState]) => {
      // Do something ... use selectors, dispatch action etc.
    });
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention. I'm using only facades and I'm not using effects anymore (I return the result directly in facades).

Comment: Effect is just one example. You can just inject your store to access data you need. So in your facade inject your store use a selector or withLatestFromOperator within observables and fetch the data you need